# Tab bar blinking during animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I use [tab bar horizontal animation](https://github.com/franklinsch/iOSScrollingTabBarAnimation/blob/master/ScrollingTabBarDemo/ScrollingTabBarUtils.swift) and during the animation, all screen like obscured, like a selected item, and when the animation is ended screen becomes normal. It looks like some blinking. I can prepare some video, but maybe somebody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used NavigationController in each controller of my tab, so the solution is to uncheck "Translucent" checkbox in storyboard on NavigationController element.